# Creating a tree in python given nodes and their positions

Tags: python, tree

I have an XML file which contains different nodes of data that I randomly generated. What I want to do is run through each node and create a tree out of it. My customized software uses the XML data to draw these nodes and their connections visually.

There is no criteria for which node connects to which; given 500 nodes, I want the ability to generate a tree with a decently complex breadth and depth.

I'm coding this in python using a customized library that draws diagrams using JgraphX so there's no point for me to show the exact code. But assume that I have the following 3 functions:

```
getXY_coord(a), get the XY coord of the node on the diagram
connectNodes(a,b), connects node a with b
getAllNodes(), returns list of all nodes on diagram
```

How would I approach making this complex tree? It doesn't even have to be visually organized, a node can connect to another node on the opposite side of the diagram, as long as the connections themselves are complex.

The only thing I was able to pull off was to randomize the list of nodes and connect the nodes adjacent in the list. This doesn't get what I want however.

Comment: Are you talking about a tree or a directed graph (or even may be an undirected graph)? there is a huge difference, both in structure and in term of algorithm you can use. Can you also explain, why your solution isn't exactly what you expected? may be show us a picture of the wanted result.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at Minimum Spanning Tree algorithms like [Prim's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm).

The `networkx` module will do this for you - see [the documentation](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.mst.minimum_spanning_tree.html#networkx.algorithms.mst.minimum_spanning_tree).